# Name of a Fantasy Book Series - Man of Two Waters/Two Rivers, Late 80's, Early 90's

Tags: story-identification, books

Looking for he name of a two or three book fantasy series that came out in the mid to late 80's, early 90's about a guy who gets powers after he is stabbed/killed in this special place where waters converge from different areas. He had the title "man of two waters," "two rivers" or something like that. Has a love interest who is telling his story to their kid at the end of the series after his death.

Used to have the books but they got five-fingered years ago.

Comment: Any chance you remember other details? Maybe you can describe the cover? [This list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) is extremely helpful in helping us help you, if you go in and [edit] in any details you remember, the probability of identification goes up dramatically!

Answer (score 2):

Is there any chance this is the *Wheel of Time* series by Robert Jordan (and later Brandon Sanderson)?

The first book was out around 1990 I believe, and it features a man (check) from a place called Two Rivers (check) who is injured (check) and goes on to develop powers (check).

He *kind of* dies at the end (although in reality he inhabits another's body, but people believe him to be dead).

However, he actually has three love interests rather than one, which is a big part of the series (he does have children with one of the women, I can't remember if we see them in the epilogue and/or if Elayne, their mother, is the one telling the story), and it's a lot bigger than two or three books (15 by the end).

Comment: Of course, it should have only _taken_ three...

Comment: For a series where characters can use powers to instantly travel anywhere on the planet, he sure spent a _lot_ of page time having armies slowly march all over the place :)